# is there anyway to populate nodes when type a custom content type value using node reference in drupal 7

Tags: entities, nodes

is there anyway to populate nodes when type a custom content type value using node reference in drupal 7 ?

node refernce populate nodes when we start typing the title of the nodes . is there any option in drupal 7 that we type custom field and it populate the related nodes as it is working with the title.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can select a View in Content Settings in "VIEWS - NODES THAT CAN BE REFERENCED".

Let that View return whatever field values you want to return.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the widget type from "autocomplete" to "select list" of the node reference field of your content type at manage fields page.

Comment: thanks to all for there replies. but it did not solve my problem. i used node reference. when i start typing the titles of node than it displays options . i want to  type a custom field other than title than it should display me the options of nodes which have this value of custom filed ex- postalcode. drupal should populate nodes which have the postalcode which i type.  thanks

Comment: @eweb Yeah right

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right, you have a content type with node reference field, so when you refer a node instead of having node suggestions directly you want them to filter down by provided content type name.

Just to make sure you did'n miss this while adding the node reference fields you will get the option of choosing the content type as "Content types that can be referenced",this is one layer where you can filter/limit the node suggestions.
But yes there are chances when you want to filter the suggestions on the fly,which will be interesting to have.

here is my view for implementing this-

- Build a custom autocomplete field ,backend for this can be served by a custom query.
- keep the node reference field as hidden field.
- While saving the node assign value(nid) in custom field to hidden node reference field.

**Edit**
 Easier way will be overiding node_reference_autocomplete_value() in node_reference.module